# regular expression to filter an array of strings by excluding those that start with '.'

Tags: c++, regex, filter

I have a string array of the list of directory contents. I want to list all the strings that don't start with "." (i.e. non hidden names).

> The constraints imposed by the context require a Regex solution that works in C++. This cannot be changed.

For example, given this:

```cpp
string fileList[] = {"test.png", "Hellozip.zip", "123.mp3", "hid.mp3", "hid.file.png", "sp ace.png", "comm(a.mp3", ".Hidden.txt"};
```

`".hid.mp3"` and `".Hidden.txt"` should be filtered out.

Here is test code for which the regex must work:

```
string fileList[] = {"test.png", "Hellozip.zip", "123.mp3", "hid.mp3", "hid.file.png", "sp ace.png", "comm(a.mp3", ".Hidden.txt"};

for(auto& file : fileList)
{
    if (std::regex_match(file, std::regex(fileRegex, std::regex_constants::icase)) == true)
    {
        cout << file << " - Match\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << file << " - No Match\n";
    }
}
```

I tried the following but it doesn't work:

```cpp
string fileRegex = "\[\\w-\]*\\.{0,1}\[\\w- ()\]*\\.(png|jpg|zip|mp3|txt)";
```

The solution doesn't need to worry about handling the special cases of  ".", "..".

Comment: This is utterly trivial without a regular expression. Is there a good reason for making it harder?

Comment: Why use a regex for this? Wouldn't it be easier to check the first character for a `.`, and drop the file? Then add the `.` and `..` to the list afterwards (since *every* directory has those)?

Comment: Another hint use [`std::string::find_first_of('.')`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of)

Comment: Are you familiar with the phrase "now you have two problems"? Google it if not.

Comment: @JerryCoffin On most (all?) unix-like systems, the root directory has a `..` linking back to root.

Comment: I need to use the existing function (not to modify since this is used by other functions), so I cannot modify function parameters...

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about

```
 ^[^.].*$
```

seems to work

Comment: And you can check the regex using this website: https://regex101.com/